# Cannot get a response from host, but only from my internet connection

Tags: http, hosting, connection

I'm trying to connect to a website that I own. It's a domain that points to a shopify store.

The browser just hangs when attempting to load the site. When I issue a request using curl I get the following:

```
$ curl -vvv samarkanddesign.com                                                                                                                                                                  
*   Trying 23.227.38.65:80...
* Connected to samarkanddesign.com (23.227.38.65) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: samarkanddesign.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

And nothing else happens until I kill the process.

Strangely though, this problem only manifests when connecting from my home internet. When I connect via a VPN, or my cellular connection the site loads fine.

All other websites, including other Shopify sites and the shopify admin, seem to work fine from my home internet connection.

Any suggestions on how to diagnose this? What could cause it to only be failing from my home connection. If I was being rate-limited I'd expect shopify to respond with a 429, but I'm not getting any response at all.

DNS seems fine and the IP that's resolved is correct.

Update:

It appears other sites that are hosted with shopify and whose domains point to the same IP (23.227.38.65) are also not responding.

If I ping the IP directly I get the following:

```
$ ping 23.227.38.65                                                                                                                                                                              
PING 23.227.38.65 (23.227.38.65): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

But if I activate my VPN and try again if works fine:

```
$ ping 23.227.38.65                                                                                                                                                                             
PING 23.227.38.65 (23.227.38.65): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 23.227.38.65: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=65.015 ms
64 bytes from 23.227.38.65: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=77.526 ms
64 bytes from 23.227.38.65: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=88.251 ms
```